# Target a sub-document with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page with a Scorm document generated in an iFrame (with iSpring). Is there a way to apply CSS rules to it from the website with JQuery ? (see the grey background in the picture below from chrome's dev tool, represented as '#document')

[image]

I tried but as the scorm document is generated after the page, JQuery doesn't recognize it...

Comment: IIRC, you cannot target elements loaded within an iFrame, due to cross domain security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your question is basically how to target/manipulate the content of an iframe using jQuery. You may [`.contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) for this. E.g. for changing the `background-color`:

`$( "iframe" ).contents().find( "body" ).css( "background-color", "hotpink" );`

Edit: Using something like this might ensure, that the iFrame-content is already loaded:

```
$( "iframe").on("load", function() {
  $(this).contents().find( "body" ).css( "background-color", "hotpink" );
});
```

Comment: Yes sorry, I edited the topic. Your solution doesn't work unfortunately :/ I'm starting to think it's impossible as the content of the iFrame is generated after the page..

Comment: It definitely works, already used it in the past. You need to make sure, however, that the iFrame-content is already loaded, when starting to manipulate it!